Global existence of an ODE
In the lecture, we often consider the following ODE $$u^{\prime} = u - u^3.$$ Since I haven't had anything to do with ODEs for a long time, I wanted to ask, is there a way (without solving it concretely) to guarantee the existence of the solution for all times $t \in \mathbb{R}$? My problem is that the function $f(t,u) = u-u^3$ is not Lipschitz continuous in the $u$ variable, or am I wrong?

Obviously $u=0$ is a solution.

@Lucenaposition I am aware that you can solve it explicitly for each initial value. However, I wanted to know if you can use the theorem for global solutions to the ODE without having to solve it directly for the first time.

I think $x-x^3$ locally Lipschitz on $(-\infty,\ +\infty)$, right?

It is straightforward to show that a solution exists in the forward direction (the solution is bounded, hence essentially a global Lipschitz problem). It blows up in the negative direction, but some work with differential inequalities is needed (by me, at least) to show this.

I added an answer to your question that deal with the global part of the solution. I do not wish to usurp the other answer, but it is incomplete.

To guarantee the existence of a global solution (you can't in general), you need to look at the forward dynamics $u'=f(u)$ and the reverse dynamics $u'=-f(u)$.
Let $f(u) = u-u^3$, note that $f(u) = 0 $ iff $u \in E = \{-1,0,1\}$. Note that on the four open intervals created by $E$, $f$ necessarily is non zero (and the sign remains constant in the interval, of course).
In both cases, if $u_0 \in E$, then $u(t) = u_0$ for all $t$. Furthermore, by uniqueness, note that if $u_0$ is in one of the connected components of $E^c$, then it must remain in that component for as long as it is defined.
The forward dynamics are straightforward:
If $u_0 < -1$ then $f(u) \ge 0$ and so $u_0 \le u(t) < -1$ for all $t \ge 0$. The latter holds because $f$ is (uniformly) Lipschitz on $[u_0,-1]$. In a similar manner, if $-1< u_0 < 0$ then $f(u) < 0$ and hence $-1 < u(t) \le u_0$ for all $t \ge 0$, and similarly for the other two intervals. In fact, it is straightforward to show that all forward solutions converge to an element of $E$.
The reverse dynamics are more subtle. In a manner similar to above, we can show that if $|u_0|<1$, then $u(t) \to 0$ (or bounded and exists for all time if you do not care about showing the limit).
If $u_0>1$, then $u$ blows up in finite time. To see this, proceed by contradiction and suppose $u$ is defined for all $t \ge 0$. First, note that $u(t) \ge  u_0$ for all $t \ge 0$. This follows because $f(u_0) >0$. Since $u'(t) =f(u(t)) \ge f(u_0)>0$ for all $t \ge 0$, we see that there is some $t_1>0$ such that $u(t) \ge 2$ for all $t \ge t_1$.
Now note that $u^3-u > u^2$ for $u \ge 2$, and so we see that
$u'(t) > (u'(t))^2$ for $t \ge t_1$.
A slight aside to consider the equation $v'=v^2$ for $t \ge t_1$ with $v(t_1) > 0$. It is straightforward to show that the solution is
$v(t) = {1 \over { {1 \over v(t)}+ t_1-t}}$, and that $v(t) \uparrow +\infty$ as $t \to \infty$.
I claim that $u(t) > v(t)$ for all $t > t_1$. It should be clear that this must be true on a small interval $(t_1, t_2)$, so suppose not and let $T>t_1$ be the first time that $u(T) = v(T)$. However this implies that $u'(T) \le v(T)$ which contradicts the assumption. Hence $u(t) > v(t)$ for all $t \ge t_1$ and hence $u$ blows up (in the reverse direction ) in finite time.
A similar analysis shows that if $u_0<-1$, then $u$ blow up (well, down) in finite time.
This is more than you were looking for, but a nice book (analysis heavy) that deals (briefly) with differential inequalities is "Differential analysis" by T.M. Flett.

Since $f(u)=u-u^3$ is locally Lipschitz, the IVP $u'=f(u),u(t_0)=u_0$ has a unique solution $u=u(t)$ in $(t_0,t_0+\delta)$ for any $u_0\in \mathbb R$ for small $\delta>0$. Extend $u=u(t)$ to the maximal interval $(t_0,t_1)$. If $t_1=\infty$, we are done. Otherwise $t_1<\infty$ such that
$$ \lim_{t\to t_1^-}|u(t)|=\infty.\tag1 $$
On the other side,multiplying both sides of the equation by $u$ gives
$$ (u^2)'=2(u^2-u^4)\le 2u^2. $$
Integrating from $t_0$ to $t$ ($t<t_1$) gives
$$ u^2(t)\le u^2(t_0)+2\int_{t_0}^tu^2(s)ds \tag2 $$
By using Gronwall's inequality (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) for (2), one has
$$ u^2(t)\le u^2(t_0)e^{2(t-t_0)}. \tag3$$
Letting $t\to t_1^-$ in (3) will give
$$ \lim_{t\to t_1^-}|u^2(t)|<\infty. $$
which is against (1). So the IVP $u'=f(u),u(t_0)=u_0$ has a unique global solution $u=u(t)$ in $(t_0,\infty)$ for any $t_0,u_0\in \mathbb R$.

Note that the above does not show the existence of a global solution.
